# Show the node creation date in admin/content

Tags: nodes, 7

In Drupal 7, I can show the creation date for the single nodes, in their pages. The creation date isn't shown in admin/content, though.

> [image: No "sort by creation date" column here]

Is there a way to add a creation date column to the node list on admin/content?

Answer (score 9):

I believe the purpose of this module [Administration Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) is exactly what you are asking for. 
Once you install it, it will allow you to override your "content" page.
This way you can add extra columns, sorting and filters to that page, using the Views UI.

The View you are looking for is called Administration: Nodes (at least in D7) and if you edit that and add fields, they will show up on the content overview page. (comment by [@Neograph734](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/9921/neograph734))

- You would need to edit this view, by navigating to the admin/structure/views/view/admin_views_node URL.
- Add the "Content: Post date" to the field of that view [image]
- Configure the new field; set the Date format to "Short" and possible renaming its label to sth like "Created". [image]
- You can optionally rearrange your columns and also make the new "Created" column Sortable in the Table format setting
- Save your view and visit the admin/content URL, it should now look similar to this: [image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is the correct answer and the way it is handled in D8.

Comment: The View you are looking for is called `Administration: Nodes` (at least in D7) and if you edit that and add fields, they will show up on the content overview page.

Comment: Did anyone else stuff around for ages looking for 'Created date' or 'Authored on'? Literally everything but 'Post date'?

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you don't want to use the Administration Views module as suggested previously, you can create a View of your content with the field you want. If you use the [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module, you can also add operations that include the actions you can do on on admin page.